# Open/Toggle a Elementor Popup - Thank You Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, popup, elementor

I would like to open a popup on the Thank-You-Page (Order-received Endpoint) of a Woocommerce Store that I have created with Elementor. - Independent of payment method. (Paypal, Cash on Delivery, etc.)

### The Popup Shortcode:
[elementor-template id="6485"]

I have now added the following code to the Function.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_', 'nlmedia1_thankyou');

function nlmedia1_thankyou() {
  echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="6485"]');
}
```

---

I also tried it for different payment gateways.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_COD', 'nlmedia1_thankyou');

function nlmedia1_thankyou() {
  echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="6485"]');
}
```

Unfortunately, none of this has worked and I have not been able to find anything in this regard until now.

I would be glad about any help regarding the embedding of the trigger for an elementor popup. LG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

#1

Downloaded this Plugin:
Popup Trigger URL for Elementor Pro - Suki WordPress Theme

= Shows Popup URL.

#2

Function.php:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout' );
function woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout() {
    global $wp;
    POPUP_URL_HERE
    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) && empty($_GET['popup']) ) {

        $redirect_url = home_url('/kasse/order-received/'.$wp->query_vars['order-received'].'/?key='.$_GET['key'].'&popup=openPOPUP_URL_HERE');
        wp_redirect($redirect_url );
        exit;
    }
```

*POPUP_URL_HERE = Enter the URL of your Popup.
(Dashboard > Templates > Popups > Trigger URLs > Show URLs)

- /Kasse = Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's the best solution for this

```
// Open Popup like Thanks you Page
jQuery(function($) {
  $.ajax = new Proxy($.ajax, {
    apply(target, prop, [options]) {
      const { url, success } = options;

      if (url === WC_CHECKOUT_URL && success) {
        const $form = $('.checkout woocommerce-checkout');

        options.success = function(result) {
          const isSuccess = 'success' === result.result && $form.triggerHandler( 'checkout_place_order_success' ) !== false;

          if (isSuccess) {
            const orderId = result.redirect.match(/\/(\d+)\//)[1];

            $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            $form.unblock();

            // need call for detachUnloadEventsOnSubmit
            success({ result: 'fake' });

            // Open Popup
            $.magnificPopup.open({
              items: {
                src: '#modal-success-order',
              },
              mainClass: 'mfp-zoom-in',
              type: 'inline',
              closeOnBgClick: true,
              showCloseBtn:false,
              callbacks: {
                open: function() {
                  const $content = $(this.content[0]);
                  $content.find('#order_id').text(orderId);
                },
                close: function(){
                  window.location = '/';
                },
              },
            });

            return;
          }

          success(result);
        }
      }
      return target(options);
    },
  });
});
```